# Backslashes in regexp pattern for PHP

Tags: regex, url

I'm trying to perform a regex operation in my PHP code (preg_replace). Now I'm working with:

```
|^http(s)?://[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$|i
```

That matches URLs like http://google.com, etc... but now I'm guessing what if the URL I want to match is also like this one?

```
http:\/\/asd.domain.com\/path\/of\/url\/something.else
```

I've tried with 2x backslashes and 4x backslashes and it doesn't seem to work.

Any advice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That certainly is no valid URL if it really contains literal backslashes.

Comment: Well, I'm treating it as a string, so it doesn't matter. What I want to achieve with the regex is to make it a valid URL

Comment: This smells like you are trying to work around some small issue instead of solving the cause. Why don't you check which syntax you expect and then work with that clean and valid information? Why do you suddenly get another representation? It is "either or" usually!

Comment: Just use other delimiters than `/`. If you use something like `#` or `~` as delimiter you wouldn't need to escape backslashes. Simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you simply want to match the string, add some backslashes:

```
^http(s)?:\\?/\\?/[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(:[0-9]+)?(\\?/.*)?$
```

I used a `?` quantifier so that it still matches the URLs it could match before that. Since `\` is an escaping character, you need two of those, the first to escape the escaping properties of the second `\`.

See [demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/fL9rS6) (I only escaped forward slashes there because of how the regex tester works -- the delimiters are slashes).

Comment: The number of backslashes required for escaping the backslashes actually depends on _how_ you define that pattern string since it might get interpreted at that stage...

Comment: @arkascha Right. Maybe I should have mentioned that double backslashes are for literal regex strings. Double escaping is just too tedious though imo ^^;